# How can I blend the gradient from two rectangles in different directions?

Tags: inkscape, blending, lighting-effects

I need help with trying to reproduce and effect using Inkscape. The problem which I have is with shades in two different directions. This effect can be seen in the screenshot from below.

[image: Sketch of the problem]

As it can be seen there is a gradient "blended" resulting from two gradients one vertical and the other is horizontal.

I don't know how to reproduce this. I've attempted to do this on Inkscape, but it didn't turned out the way how I wanted to be. This can be seen in the screenshot from below.

[image: Sketch of the problem]

The result was the overlapping of two gradients, and I can't seen to find a proper way to match the desired result. Looking the effect is that the gradient at the corner doesn't look straight or right but instead is smooth and rounded. Does it exist a way to make this?

**How** can I achieve that effect so the corner doesn't look overlapped?. How can I do that?. Can someone help me?.

Answer (score 2):

Use a different method instead. This is for Inkscape 1.0

1. Do *Filters > Shadows & Glows > Drop Shadow* to add a Drop Shadow to a white filled rectangle with a black stroke. Set the Horizontal and Vertical offsets to 0, adjust the Blur radius to your preference.

[image]

2. Open the filter editor using *Filters > Filter Editor*, then select the Gaussian Blur, and choose the Filter General settings tab, and click once* on the + or - on each of the dimensions. This will make the filter extent editable and you can now click and drag the diamond shaped handles to make it the size you want.

[image]

*Note: The reason this is needed is because of a little bug in Inkscape 1.0. Changing the dimensions very slightly allows the diamond handles to then be moved by clicking and dragging.

Also note that older versions of Inkscape don't have the click and drag diamond handles for changing the extent of the Filter, but you can still edit the dimensions and co-ordinates manually in the Filter Editor.

Comment: I'm using Inkscape 0.91 and I've updated the question. How do I create a drop shadow filter to the rectangle?. Since I'm still novice, can you include more steps?. I don't know where to find those tools.

Comment: Do *Filters > Shadows & Glows > Drop Shadow*.  The Filter editor can be found under *Filters > Filter Editor*. Inkscape 0.91 doesn't have diamond handles you can drag, however you can still set the dimensions and co-ordinates manually.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell - I've updated the answer now.

Comment: Okay! But... I'm still stuck on how do I trim the upper part and the rest on the right?. I only require the L shaped bottom. I'm still having the black stroke. But in the example it uses a different stroke color. The pick color tool gave me this color 231f20ff. Can you help me with this part please?.

Comment: @ChrisStenbeck, just edit the filter extent so it crops your rectangle. [See example](https://imgur.com/cLQ1WAz). You can change the stroke colour in the Fill & Stroke panel (Shift+Ctrl+F). You can also remove the stroke in that panel if you don't want it.

Comment: Nice! I suggest you can add the imgur image as part of your answer in the bottom as a note. But there are still some unattended questions. *How did you come with the blur radius to be 19.8?* What does horizontal offset and vertical offset do and why did you pick them to be 0?. What's a Gaussian blur?. Will the effect be affected if the object is turned into a path?. You instructed me to make a rectangle with a black stroke, will I obtain the same effect using a different color and that color produce the same grading?. Do the rectangle needs to be filled with white for that effect?

Comment: When I use the filter extend it crops the rectangle but this causes the image to "increase" in size leaving a white part which I don't need. Does it exist a way to crop this part?. Or a method which crops the result to be less wider and more tight to the original object?. I've attempted to do difference between paths but this doesn't work that well. Can you help me with this part?.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell - I didn't say the blur radius needs to be 19.8.  Read the answer again.  Horizontal and Vertical offset moves the shadow position. Also the cropped part of the rectangle is invisible - so nobody will know it's there except you. Just leave it there, there's no need to get rid of it. Non-destructive editing is better anyway.. Also we don't usually do full tutorials here. We expect users to be familiar with the basics.  You don't need to use Difference for this method, and it wouldn't work anyway, because then the gradient wouldn't fill the L shape as in the example image.

Comment: Okay, I'm sorry for asking about a tutorial, as I mentioned there are some tools which I'm not familiar on how to use them or what's their application, perhaps this might be a part of a separate question. Yes I've read your answer, in the screenshot the blur radius is set to that number. I was just curious how did you came to that value, was that by trial and error just looking at the shade of the image or was by picking the color from a portion of the image?. I do understand that the white portion is invisible but it occupies a space of the image which I tend to minize.

Comment: The reason for making the image tight is due I intend to trim the sides in the end when the image is completed. I often do this by going to document properties and resize to fit to contents, but when you do this the size is affected by the largest object put in place. This was the main reason for my second question in the comments. The method of using drop shadow seems to be distorted or altered when I resize the object even using the lock in proportions. I other words the shadow becomes lighter and more white in the outher edges. If I try to use the effect again then it darkens.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use interpolated strokes, with interpolated color, and then grouping them, blurring them, and setting a clip around them.

Result could look like this:

[image: gradient frame]

Comment: The effect doesn't look very close to the example. Its more dark in the outher edges, does it exist a way to add more light into it so it matches with the example?. I don't know how to use the tools you mentioned. Can you explain where are them and how did you used it?.

Comment: @chris-steinbeck-bell The colors can be selected freely. This is only an example. There are a couple pitfalls that one can fall into, with the clipping and path directions. This example is only suitable if you know how to work around them. I'll try and make a video (I did, and my recorder failed multiple times before I gave it up). It's still going to be difficult for a beginner, even with a video.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell https://youtu.be/q6kcMcNVNUM

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell https://youtu.be/cBw5xSSN4i0 (using a gradient mesh)

Answer (score 0):

You can get something resembling without making any slick effect edits. Use blur, the one which can be set with a slider in Objects and Stroke&Fill panels.

Blur tends to make a rectangle too round, but you can compensate it:

[image]

A black rectangle is drawn. It's converted to a Bezier curve by applying Path > Object to path. Edge midpoint nodes are inserted by double clicking with the node tool. The new nodes are moved a little inwards. In the right quite heavy blur is inserted with the Blur slider in the Objects panel.

NOTE: The nodes are still adjustable with the node tool if needed.

Make a frame. Draw 2 rectangles. Their colors are meaningless. Align them, select both and apply Path > Subtract:

[image]

Place the frame on the blurred shape. Select both and apply Object > Clip > Set.

[image]

It's still editable. You can release the clip for edits, but the blurred shape can also be edited directly. Double click it or select it in the objects panel.

NOTE 2: The result is partially transparent. Insert an opaque white background, maybe a copy of the frame if needed.

NOTE 3: Starting from a grey rectangle can create the wanted gradient with less blur. No roundness compensation may be needed.

Comment: Like the other method using blur slider in objects makes them bigger than the original size. The dark portion in the middle is hidden and the object is tight to the frame size when you use clip tool. I was intending to delete the dark portion in the middle, does it exist a way to achieve this?. The other part is how do I add the contour in the inner part of the L?. Does it has to be drawn manually using bezier tool?.

Comment: Instead of a subtracted frame you can use a rectangle to clip the blurred shape. Use the smaller rectangle to cover the dark mid part. The rectangle can have black stroke.